# Sinatra Ruby iterate SQLite data into one HTML column

Tags: html, ruby, sqlite, sinatra, erb

I've got the following SQLite table in my Sinatra app:

```
+----------------------------------+
| location             area        |
+----------------------------------+
| Maine                 1          |
| Syracuse              2          |
| Northport             3          |
| NYC                   4          |
| Coatesville           4          |
| Erie                  4          |
| Dayton                5          |
| Chicago               6          |
| Dallas                6          |
+----------------------------------+
```

I'd like to create an HTML table from this data that looks like the following:

```
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Area 1</th>
                <th>Area 2</th>
                <th>Area 3</th>
                <th>Area 4</th>
                <th>Area 5</th>
                <th>Area 6</th>                    
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Maine</td>
                  <td>Syracuse</td>
                  <td>NorthPort</td>
                  <td>NYC</td>
                  <td>Dayton</td>
                  <td>Chicago</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Coatesville</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Dallas</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>Erie</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td> 
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I can easily iterate through each area and the locations contained within with two nested loops, but because of the way td and tr work in tables I'm not sure how to iterate each area's locations into a single column

I think I've got the table head down:

```
          <thead>
            <tr>
          <% @table_areas.each do |x| %>
            <th><%= x.area %></th>
            <% end %>
            </tr>
          </thead>
```

but I can't seem to figure out the rest. The areas and locations within each area will be changing frequently, so I need this to be created dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
<% tas = @table_areas.group_by(&:area) %>
<% counter = tas.values.map(&:length).max %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <% tas.keys.each do |x| %>
        <th><%= 'Area ' + x.to_s %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% (0...counter).each do |i| %>
      <tr>
        <% tas.values.each do |x| %>
          <td><%= x[i] && x[i].location %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You may need to do some `to_i` manipulation if area numbers are stored as strings in your database

Comment: Nice, I ended up using Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to position the columns as side by side divs, but your solution looks good too. There's many ways to get the job done